# In my React app CSSTransition stacks components vertically during transition

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-transitions, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use `TransitionGroup` and `CSSTransition` together with `react-router-dom` to create smooth transitions between pages. For debugging purposes I've set the fade transition time to 5 seconds.

Here's my `App` component:

```js
function Inner(): React.ReactElement {
  const location = useLocation()
  const currentKey = location.pathname.split("/")[1] || "/"
  return (
    <TransitionGroup component="div" className="main">
      <CSSTransition key={currentKey} timeout={5000} classNames="fade">
        <Switch location={location}>
          <Route path="/guild" component={Guild} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  )
}

function App(): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="*">
        <Inner />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

It's properly nested inside `React` as well as my Redux `Provider` and `react-router-dom`'s `BrowserRouter` in my `index.tsx` file:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

And the CSS for the fade:

```css
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity 5000ms ease-in !important;
}

.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.fade-exit.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: opacity 5000ms ease-in !important;
}
```

For demonstration purposes I've set up my `Home` and `Guild` components to link to each other, so I can go back and forth. What should happen is they should fade into each other during the transition.

Instead what happens is the new component immediately appears vertically above the other component with opacity 0, pushing the old component vertically downward. Then the transition starts happening and gradually the new component that's on top fades in while the old component that's below fades out. Once the transition is done the old component is unmounted.

I've tried everything I can think of to prevent the newly appearing component from pushing down the old component. They should be layered directly on top of each other to give the impression of one component fading into the other component. All the examples I've found online seem to do this. As far as I can tell I'm doing thing's exactly the same as they are.

Here's what the page looks like after loading it:

[image]

And here's what it looks like immediately after clicking a guild:

[image]

Notice how the guild component (for now it's just a page saying "Coming Soon...") pops in above the home component.

Then after a few seconds:

[image]

See how the top fades in as the bottom fades out. This would be working perfectly if they were overlaid on top of each other instead of being stacked vertically.

Then finally, after the animation ends:

[image]

Comment: May I suggest getting all this into a sandbox? That would make a lot easier to troubleshoot for us.

Comment: You have to have the parent or root of each page be `position: absolute;` Probably at `top: 0; left: 0;` but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

@DCTID was correct! I just needed to have `position: absolute` set for `.fade-enter` and `.fade-exit`.